# Leakage out of `overflow:hidden` parent with rounded border in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Cropped by rounded parent child's hidden part still persists and active in Chrome:

[image: Cursor pointer firing outside rounded parent]

The same behavior in IE could be cured by adding `z-index` property to parent. Still found no cure for Chrome.

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}

#element {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a09q6cw2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For versions of chrome that support `-webkit-clip-path`, you can clip the child at the same boundaries as the parent and prevent the cursor change outside the parent :

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 0px -50px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, `-webkit-clip-path` solves the issue for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[Please check this may be works for you..](http://jsfiddle.net/gre53ugm/1/)

CSS

```
.cricle {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
 position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100px; /*this value same with first value of clip-path top value*/
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 0px 0px);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="cricle">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for it, it does solve the issue, but I have accepted preceding answer.

Answer (score -1):

Its a basic HTML rendering for parent and child.
You have just given `overflow:hidden` for the parent,so the part of child which is out of parent boundary has been clipped off.but in no where you have hidden the child div right?so how you expect it to be under parent div?

If you can swap the parent and child div see how the html will look like.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
}
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide the child div i think you have to specify `display:none` for it.

Comment: The point was to make hidden part of a child element to be clipped truly and not to intercept mouse events.

Comment: you misunderstood the question

Answer (score -1):

if you want to support ie maybe [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) can help:

```css
#rect {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200"
 viewPort="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>

    </clipPath>
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="orange"
      clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
<rect id="rect" x="100" y="150" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"
      clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Don't know why your answer was blackballed, but anyway `z-index` mentioned, while lacks an explanation, still is far more compact and easier solution.

Comment: at first I looked into `-webkit-clip-path` and `clip-path` CSS property (like @web-tiki 's answer) but that 's lacking ie support while SVG clipPath should be supported also from IE9 onwards...

Comment: See no IE9 compatibility issues with common CSS-way as well, since IE here functions properly and has no need for `clip-path`.

Comment: thought there was ; my bad